# List object has no attribute columns

Tags: python, pandas, scaling

I am trying to perform *min-max scaling* on the simple dataset

```
data2 = [10, 20, 35, 70, 100]
```

The following code is giving me an error

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'

```
def min_max_scaling(df):
df_norm = df.copy()
for col in df_norm.columns:
    df_norm[col] = (df_norm[col] - df_norm[col].min()) / (df_norm[col].max() - df_norm[col].min())
return df_norm

df_normalized = min_max_scaling(data3)

df_normalized
```

Comment: a list is not a dataframe even if you call it df

Comment: @Chris, Spot on! Just fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your min_max_scaling function is expecting a pandas dataframe instance but you are passing it a List. Changing the code as follows should work.

```
import pandas as pd

def min_max_scaling(df):
    df_norm = df.copy()
    for col in df_norm.columns:
        df_norm[col] = (df_norm[col] - df_norm[col].min()) / (df_norm[col].max() - df_norm[col].min())
    
    return df_norm

data2 = [10, 20, 35, 70, 100]

data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df_normalized = min_max_scaling(data2)

print(df_normalized)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you you have a dataframe `df` and for each column in df, you want to do a (max-min) scalscaling?

Then you should not pass a list but a dataframe to your functions.

```
def min_max_scaling(df):
    df_norm = df.copy()
    for col in df_norm.columns:
        df_norm[col] = (df_norm[col] - df_norm[col].min()) / (df_norm[col].max() - df_norm[col].min())
    return df_norm


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df_normalized = min_max_scaling(df)
```